# View curl from left to right and right to left in Ios6

Tags: ios, animation, curl

I have to curl a view from left to right and vice versa as like book page.i have no idea plz suggest me....sample code will be more helpfull for me...

Comment: Should user be able to touch and move the view curl up/down or just programmatically up/down, no user touch needed?

Comment: The user  be able to touch and move but the curl will be from left to right and right to left.

Answer (score 0):

This is only valid for iOS5 and higher, but it might be ok for you. Take a look at [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html). I does all the hard work for you. The documentation also has a link to a sample project.

Comment: but in my app i am not using the pageviewcontroller, i have to animate the view as the UIPageviewcontroller from left to right and right to left.